# Warning: Undefined array key "name" in C:\Users\navig\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Frontend\api.php on line 2 и так по line 4 and 6

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']),
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var(trim($_POST['Email']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if(mb_strlen($name) < 3 || mb_strlen($name) > 50) {
    echo "name password";
    exit();
}
if(mb_strlen($email) < 5 || mb_strlen($email) > 40) {
    echo "name password";
    exit();
}
if(mb_strlen($password) < 5 || mb_strlen($password) > 50) {
    echo "2 to 6 characters";
    exit();
}

$mysql = new mysqli("Register-log", "root", "", "Register-log");
$mysql->query('INSERT INTO `users` (name, email, password)
VALUES($name,$email $password)');

//закрытие БД
$mysql->close();
?>
html 

 <!--  forma входа-->
                    <div class="form-box">
                      <form action="api.php" class="form form_signin" method="post">
                        <h3 class="form__title">sign in</h3>

                        <p>
                          <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="name">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <input type="password" class="form__input" placeholder="password">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <button class="form__btn send-button">sign in</button>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <a href="#" class="form__fogot">restore password</a>
                        </p>
                      </form>

                      <!-- Block регистрация -->

                      <form action="api.php" class="form form_signup" method="post">
                        <h3 class="form__title">Registration</h3>

                        <p>
                          <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="name">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <input type="email" class="form__input" placeholder="Email">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <input type="password" class="form__input" placeholder="password">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <button class="form__btn form__btn_signup send-button">Registration</button>
                        </p>

                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </article>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В пост запрос нужно правильно данные отправлять 
Вроде бы норм отправил но ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему вы не воспользовались переводчиком... Там пишет:

> Неопределенный ключ массива "имя"

Что говорит явно о том, что нет такого ключа. Когда его не может быть? Если рассудить чисто логически - наверное тогда, когда форма не отправлена.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский я знаю что оно пишет. Дело в том что все ключи написаны в api.php

Comment: Это что-то должно мне о чём-то говорить?

Comment: Я понимаю что есть ошибка в синтаксисе (может и нет ) мне нужно понять что я сделал не так

Comment: Я написал что сделано не так. Последние 9 слов в ответе

Comment: Алексей спасибо

Answer (score 0):

У вас не приходит один из `$_POST['']`
при использование входных данных надо проверять на существование.

```
$name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']),
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Заменяйте на подобное.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  $name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']),
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}else{
  $name = "";
}
```